# notify whenever the contents of an S3 bucket change

Tags: amazon-s3

I am able to add triggers/notifications to my lambda function whenever objects are created in an s3 bucket. I also want to get notified when objects are updated/changed.is there any way to get notified through SNS or lambda execution when the  objects in an s3 bucket are changed?

Answer (score 1):

Objects and their metadata in S3 are immutable.  The only way to "change" them is to replace them, so an `s3:ObjectCreated:*` event will capture object creation, object overwrites, and metadata updates.